# Paraphrasen gesucht: Jemandem die Sorgen nehmen

Tags: single-word-request, phrase, phrase-request

Ich suche nach Paraphrasen für folgenden Ausdruck:

> Sie haben mir die Sorgen genommen

Gibt es hierfür vielleicht sogar ein einziges Wort, das "Sorgen nehmen" in diesem Anwendungsfall vollständig umschreibt?

Comment: eventuell auch _beschwichtigen_, wobei hier _beruhigen_, wie von @Iris vorgeschlagen, besser passt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Sie haben mir die Sorgen genommen

beschreibt zwei Dinge

1. Ich hatte Sorgen
2. Jemand anderes hat sie mir genommen

Diese zwei Dinge **vollständig** in einem Wort auszudrücken ist meiner Meinung nach daher unmöglich.

Ich würde am ehesten das Synonym "beruhigen" vorschlagen: 
Sie haben mich beruhigt

Comment: Paraphrasieren bedeutet, etwas mit anderen Worten (nicht nur mit einem einzigen! ) wiedergeben. Sorgen sind etwas, das uns bedrückt. Darum sind alle Wendungen, die umschreiben, dass das Bedrückende weggenommen worden,  ist Paraphrasen  für dasselbige. Er hat mich frei gemacht! Er hat mich befreit! Er hat mich  aufgerichtet.

Comment: Danke für die Vorschläge :)

Answer (score 2):

Sie haben mich wieder aufgestellt.

Sie haben mich aufgerichtet.

Sie haben mich frei gemacht.

Sie haben mich befreit.

Comment: Danke schön für die Vorschläge :)

Comment: Warum ergänzt du nicht "Sie haben mich frei gemacht! Sie haben mich befreit!"?